# how do i embed a YouTube video in Joomla 1.5.23?

Tags: video, joomla, youtube, embed

How do I embed a YouTube video into Joomla 1.5.23? I have tried the default YouTube embed code several times but Joomla won't accept it.

Comment: Please update to 1.5.26 + the patch 31626 see here for an easy download http://anything-digital.com/blog/security-updates/joomla-updates/joomla-15-security-patch-made-easy-to-install.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ,

Create a module that have your embedded code. For module development [tutorial](http://www.walkswithme.net/joomla-module-development-tutorial)

And create an article and set the module inside that like.

```
{loadposition youtube_module_pos}
```

Inside your article just mention the module position like above
for [more](http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_put_a_module_inside_an_article?)

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the editor, configuration global: Editor: No

Or use other plugin: All Videos plugin

try Y[ouTube Embedder](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/social-media/video-channels/5533)